# Meta Keyword problem for my Laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, websecurity, meta-key

I have a [Laravel site](http://lasermedicalbd.com/).

While I use `site::http://lasermedicalbd.com/` I have got a search result like below image.

[image]

Here are lots of meta keyword with different languages those I am not using for my website.

I can't understand why and how those coming. I am worried about my website security. Is it some kind of hacking issue or malware problem?

Though I have already checked my site with two below tools for malware checking.

1. https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/lasermedicalbd.com
2. https://sg.godaddy.com/web-security/website-security-check/results?site=http%3A%2F%2Flasermedicalbd.com%2F

But nothing found.

Anybody Help Please? How can I remove or avoid these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, here maybe two reasons first. maybe this is an expired domain. that means someone uses this description(china lang) with this domain. Another reason maybe you are used before description. google take some time to update your new page description.

Comment: To solve this issue you should add a description (which is you added already). and wait for some days for google index your site and update the new description(it's take some time) if you want to fast you should submit a sitemap at google web master.